# Fortran 95, Double integral with non rectangular bounds

Tags: fortran

[Problem I am trying to work out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxGvt.png)

I am stuck trying to integrate this function, s= 0.1736901

My code is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReRLK.png)

It just spits out NaN for the value of the integral, and does not like my function.
I am basically a beginner, and I can't find any problems similar to this

Comment: Please paste your problem and code in characters (not images) on this page, so that people can help. Those links will soon expire and future readers will be left with potentially some answers but no question.

Comment: Please checkout the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on how to include code on stackoverflow (insert 3 backticks, then your code, then 3 backticks again).

Answer (score -1):

First, I OCR'ed your image to extract code from it, please edit your post to insert code instead.

The code works if you just remove the last part for `func2d` and its declaration:

```
program trap2d
!===================================
! USUAL DECLERATIONS
!===================================
Implicit none
real :: a, b, hx, hy, x, y    ! <== removed func2d 
real :: integralx, integraly
integer :: i, j, Nx, Ny
!===================================

!i is for the x part, j is for the y part

!===================================
!MAIN CODE--------------------------
! ==================================

Nx = 5 
Ny = 5
a = 2.1736501 
b = 2.1736501

hx = (a+b)/Nx 

integralx = 0.0 

do i = 0,Nx 
    x = b + i*hx
    hy = (sqrt(1+x**2)+sqrt(1+x**2))/Ny 
    integraly = 0.0 
    do j = 0,Ny
        y = sqrt(1+x**2) + j*hy
        integraly = integraly + hx*sqrt(1+y**2) 
    end do
    integralx = integraly + hx*integralx
end do

print*, integralx 

end program trap2d

! function func2d (x)
!     real :: func2d, x
!     func2d(x) = sqrt(1+x**2)
! end function func2d
```

Output:   `220.1184`

If you want to use a function, just write it like this before the `end program trap2d` line and don't declare the function at top of the main program:

```
contains

function func2d (x)
    real :: func2d, x
    func2d = sqrt(1+x**2)
end function func2d
```

Answer (score -1):

In the function definition you have a typo

```
function func2d (x)
    real :: func2d, x
    ! func2d(x) = sqrt(1+x**2)  <-  TYPO HERE
      func2d    = sqrt(1+x**2)
end function func2d
```

---

As an explanation: One need to differentiate between a function call inside the main program and the definition statement of the function's return value.

The function call could be in your case something like

```
program 
...
   y = func2d(x) + j*hy     ! you call the function `func2d` and supply the argument `x`
...
end program
```

whereas the function's return value statement was stated above as

```
function func2d(x)
...
      func2d    = sqrt(1+x**2)   ! you assign to the function's result variable a value
...
end function
```

---

Note that your program does not even call `func2d`.

Under the assumption that you actually want to call `func2d` (and not hardcode the function in the integration loops) you might want to take note from [AboAmmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599974/10774817): define the function as a contained procedure.
This way you get an explicit interface.

Comment: (If editing, it may be worth pointing out why the "typo" is a bad thing. A statement function wouldn't be defined like that, instead simply being inside the main program, but someone may think that they are.)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that `func2d(x)=...` would be fine if that were in the main program (and we were still in the 1970s), but the combination of trying to use the statement function with a function subprogram of the same name is a problem. I think I've seen more people confused by statement functions than how to assign function results, but this could be the latter case.